# Can I use the tor network in a script, won't I be abusing any rules?

Tags: abuse

I need to get some data from one website. The amount of data is big so I will need a script for this. And the site forbids the access after a dozen or so requests. I could use the tor network as a proxy to circumvent this restriction, but won't I abuse any rules / fair policy in such a case?

I mean it would be thousands requests.

Comment: I know this a bit dated for an answer, however my conclusion besides risking the TOR Port becoming blocked sig(DDos) is to examine how this flood of requests will impact the actual performance of the TOR network and the actual exit nodes themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems to be a normal Tor usage, of course if you're not violating law or cheating by doing this

Answer (score 1):

One thing to consider is that if the owners of the site realise what you're doing, and see lots of requests coming from lots of different Tor exit nodes in quick succession, they may decide to block Tor traffic completely. This may have an adverse effect on other Tor users who are using the site in more legitimate ways.

(Note that currently there are ~1000 exit nodes, giving you ~12,000 requests. That might not be enough to raise suspicions... )